# how can i show images and checkboxes in xhtml2pdf using django

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I am converting Html into pdf using xhtml2pdf using Django and this is my code

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None

def myView(request):
    pdf = render_to_pdf(pdf_template, params)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

everything's working fine till now, but I also want to show the company logo and some checkboxes on pdf and that is not working.

no error, no wrong output, just blank space in place of image and checkboxes.

Any idea of how can I get images and checkboxes in my pdf?

this is my HTML file

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="12" align="center" style="font-size:larger;">
       <img src="/static/assets/img/theme/vue.jpg">
       <input type="checkbox"> Orginal Receipt</td>        
       <u>Some Company</u>
       Phone: 123-456
       Website: www.example.com
   </td>
</tr>
```

image and checkbox are showing in normal html template but not in pdf

Comment: Hi Danish, make a template with the company logo and checkbox fixed in position and then you can write data by xhtml2pdf

Comment: you have to host your image on cdn and then pass src here

Comment: yeah!! this is an issue with xhtml2pdf... I appended my domain name in `img` src and it worked... but the checkbox issue still remains

Answer (score 0):

First, if you would like to refer to some image that considered as static files in your repo, you will have to add the "link callback" method.
also, probably you might need to run "python manage.py collectstatic".
[you can read more info about it here in the documentation](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django).

I had some problems with placing images inside table elements as well.
Try to figure out another way to place an images where you would like to (div etc...) - it worked for me